# avoid fancybox iframe closing after submit?

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, fancybox

This is really weird and it's not supposed to be happening this way but it is.

I call my FB:

```
 <p>Haz <a class="recupera" href="recover.php">click aquí</a> si has olvidado tu contraseña.</p>

 $("a.recupera").fancybox({
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false
    });
```

Inside recover.php I have a form and I handle everything there, it works when I open it in a browser and does everything fine:

```
<?
//DOCTYPE and all that jazz here
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){

//does stuff in DB

}else{
 ?>
 <div id="logeando">
<h2 class="titulo-cufon">Recuperar contraseña</h2>
<form method="post" action="" id="loginform">
<fieldset>
    <label class="titulo-cufon" for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="large button gray input" value="Enviar" />
</fieldset>
</form>
 </div>
 <?}?>
```

Everytime I click the submit button my fancybox will close. It's an iframe, why would it do that? How can I prevent it? Is it my submit buton closing it? From what I've read, people are usually asking for the oposite (the iframe closing after submit, not preventing it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify that fancybox is running in an iframe.

```
 $("a.recupera").fancybox({
        'scrolling'     : 'no',
        'titleShow'     : false,
        'type'      : 'iframe'
    });
```